# Why does the PHP set_execption_handler capture an Error object

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I'm working with error and exception handles in PHP, and am finding some unexpected behaviour when attempting to call a method that doesn't exist.

Here's the PHP:

```php
<?php
    set_error_handler(function() {
        echo 'error';
    });
    set_exception_handler(function() {
        echo 'exception';
        $args = func_get_args();
        print_r($args);
    });
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->jdhgdfkjh();
    exit(0);
```

Here's the output:

```html
exceptionArray
(
    [0] => Error Object
        (
            [message:protected] => Call to undefined method stdClass::jdhgdfkjh()
            [string:Error:private] => 
            [code:protected] => 0
            [file:protected] => /var/www/domain.com/index.php
            [line:protected] => 11
            [trace:Error:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [previous:Error:private] => 
        )

)
```

I don't really care whether it's an error or exception that occurs when trying to call a method that doesn't exist. I'm just confused as to why the exception handler is being called with an error object.

Would love some clarity if anyone has run into this before.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) says *Since PHP 7, most errors are reported by throwing Error exceptions, which will be caught by the handler as well. Both Error and Exception implements the Throwable interface*

Comment: So are you saying I only need one handler? If this call is resulting in an Error, why would it be caught the exception handler?

Comment: `set_exception_handler` is a legacy name. Since PHP 7 it does more than that name suggests. It catches all `Throwable` objects which include both `Error` and `Exception` objects. If you don't set one then you can still handle these errors in the `set_error_handler` callback but that would (I would argue) a legacy way to go about it. Note that some errors can not be caught in neither of these handlers (like parse errors for example), for those the only option you might have is `register_shutdown_function` but this can only be used for e.g. logging or cleanup

Comment: Ahh interesting okay I'm going to go back and re-evaluate how I'm setting up capturing these. If I only use a set_exception_handler, is that satisfactory? Will that catch simple Throwable errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to do my best to answer my own question. @apokryfos is right: the manual has details on this. I find it a bit confusing that the `set_exception_handler` is catching not just `Exception` and `Throwable` objects, but also `Error` objects (which are `Throwable` objects, but not `Exception` objects).

I find this confusing because `set_error_handler` has the word "error" in it, and yet, it's not catching these object-types.

So, for anyone else who stumbles on this, in newer versions of PHP, you can't expect an `Exception` object for the `set_exception_handler` callback. You need to expect a `Throwable`, and non-linearly, you may also get `Error` objects which are **not** received by the `set_error_handler`.

To deal with that in my own setup, I have the following `set_error_handler` to make things a bit cleaner:

```php
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    $args = array($errstr, $errno, E_ERROR, $errfile, $errline);
    $errorException = new \ErrorException(... $args);
});
```

This will then be caught by your `set_exception_handler` callback.
Hope this is helpful to others :)

Comment: Ok, but I would like to emphasize that the `ErrorException` "technique" will work for *non-fatal errors*. [See the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.notes)